# Sequence of numbers +++

Tags: number-sequence

Find the missing numbers in the following sequence:

> 2, 2, 4, 6, 10, 16, 26, ..., 68, ..., 178, ........

(Slightly cryptic) Hint (if you need it):

> 32 + 45 = ?

Comment: https://oeis.org/A006355 (all: https://oeis.org/search?q=2%2C+2%2C+4%2C+6%2C+10%2C+16%2C+26%2C+42%2C+68%2C+110&sort=&language=&go=Search)

Comment: I was thinking Fibonacci plus Lucas numbers. I didn't know it was same as  doubled Fibonaccis.

Answer (score 1):

> 2, 2, 4, 6, 10, 16, 26, 42, 68, 110, 178, ........

That is

> 2, 2, 4(2+2), 6(4+2), 10(4+6) , 16(8+10), 26(10+16), 42(16+26), 68(26+42), 110(42+68), 178(68_110) ..

So the missing numbers were

> 42 and 110

Answer (score 1):

> These look like the doubled Fibonacci numbers.
>  $2*1$, $2 * 1$, $2 * 2, ....$
>  So the sequence is: $2, 2, 4, 6, 10, 16, 26, 42, 68, 110, 178, 288, ...$

Answer (score 1):

This is

> The Fibonacci Sequence (next number equals previous 2 numbers added) but doubled:
> [image]

So it goes

> *2, 2, 4, 6, 10, 16, 26,* **42,** *68,* **110,** *178,* **288**... 
> ...466, 754, 1220, 1974, 3194, 5168, 8362, 13530

Answer (score 0):

The answer is very easy and written right here

> 42, 110, 288
>  each number is the sum of the previous 2.

Answer (score 0):

The missing numbers are

> 42,110,288

So the whole sequence is

> 2,2,4,6,10,16,26,42,68,110,178,288

Because

> 2+2=4,4+2=6,6+4=10,10+6=16 AND SO ON